# Unity2D - How to destroy my Instantiate particle system

Tags: unity, c#, particles, gameobject

I'm having trouble trying to destroy my Instantiated particle system, I can only destroy my gameobject

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class meteor_destruction : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject meteor_d_effect;
public GameObject meteor_explo_effect;
public GameObject meteor_explo2_effect;

public int pointsIncrement = 1;

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
{

    var effect_explo = Instantiate(meteor_explo_effect, col.gameObject.transform.position, col.transform.rotation);
    var effect_explo2 = Instantiate(meteor_explo2_effect, col.gameObject.transform.position, col.transform.rotation);
    var effect_d = Instantiate(meteor_d_effect, col.gameObject.transform.position, col.transform.rotation);
    Destroy (gameObject);
    Destroy (effect_explo,3);
    Destroy (effect_explo2,3);
    Destroy (effect_d,3);

}
```

It's generated after the meteor collide, but those 3 particle effects keeps adding inside my Hierarchy panel.

Answer (score -1):

Set the collider as a Trigger and use `void OnTriggerEnter2d (Collider2D coll)`.

A Trigger calls only once and does not keep calling the function. On collision enter function will be called multiple times.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. An `OnEnter` triggers once, regardless. `OnTriggerEnter` triggers for *kinematic* colliders, while `OnCollisionEnter` triggers for *non-kinematic* colliders.